# Minimum, preferred and maximum window sizes in a WinUI 3 application

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

What is the best and most concise way to set the minimum, preferred and maximum window sizes in a WinUI 3 application?

Before that, I developed applications in WPF and there were 3 properties that I needed, but this does not seem to be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this yet.

If you want to do this the hard way, check this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7296#issuecomment-1221030806) in the WinUI 3 repo.

But if you want to do this the easy way, just use the [WinUIEx](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/tree/7a5856ecd1f0c5b79254c1b14addae69116c1c22) NuGet package.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : WinUIEx.WindowEx
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```xml
 <winex:WindowEx xmlns:winex="using:WinUIEx"
    x:Class="DesktopWindowExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:DesktopWindowExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    MinHeight="200"
    MinWidth="100">

    <Grid/>

</winex:WindowEx>
```